# In Java how to match a character that is not a "["?

Tags: java, regex

I have a block of text that has information encoded as follows:

```
[tag 1] some text [tag 2] more text [tag 3] even more text
```

I am in the process of creating a regular expression in Java that will extract encoded information into separate strings. Such as:

```
[tag 1] some text
[tag 2] more text
[tag 3] even more text
```

The regular expression that I have created is (for regular pattern matching):  `“([.+?][^[]+)”`

This regular expression works well in Notepad++ and two online-tools:

1. http://www.regextester.com/
2. http://www.softlion.com/webTools/RegExpTest/default.aspx

In Java this regular expression statement produces a runtime exception:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(“(\\[.+?\\][^[]+)”);
```

Exception details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 13
(\[.+?\][^[]+)
             ^
```

Do I have to escape the negated "[" within the character class?  If yes how?

Comment: Try escaping it per usual `...[^\\[]+)"`.

Comment: You're escaping the first grouping brackets, why aren't you escaping the second ones as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the `[` within the negated character class.  Although this shouldn't be necessary inside of a character class, clearly Java is having an issue with it, and it does not change the meaning of the character class to escape characters that shouldn't have a special meaning within a character class.

Try the following:

```
(\[.+?\][^\[]+)
```

Or for the Java code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(“(\\[.+?\\][^\\[]+)”);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the square bracket it just like you escaped them earlier:

```
(\\[.+?\\][^\\[]+)
```

The runtime exception is being caused because the RegEx parser sees [^[] as having an unclosed bracket.

Comment: It is legal to have it unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to excape the bracket, this should work :

```
[^\\[]
```

Comment: It is legal to have it unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

The Java implementation seems to have a bug.

Normally, regex does not require you to escape it, but try escaping it anyway.

```
(\[.+?\][^\[]+)
"(\\[.+?\\][^\\[]+)"
```

It could be considered good practice to escape special characters, even if they don't need to be. It also helps avoid bugs like this.